# google maps does not show Khmer language place

Tags: java, android, json, google-maps

I want to show English and Khmer language on each place as Image below. But when I embed maps with Android App it doesn't show Khmer language.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code , this will help you to show the place name in Khmer language. please check it

```
 String languageToLoad = "hl=km";// for Cambodia language 
    Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = locale;
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
            getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

Comment: thank you so much but it did not work yet. I don't know why it show other language as Thai, Vietnam but Cambodia does not show.